# Why is App.config read only from the main project?

Tags: c#, app-config

I have two c# projects: 
1. A DAL project which consists of a sql compact.e database and a .cs file that calls the stored procs 
after reading the connection string from the project's app.config file.

2.A client project- a simple .cs that uses the DAL project to access the DB and display the results in a simply GUI.

I've ran into some issues with the DAL, since ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString was empty
 all the time and then I discoverd that if I put the connection string inside the
 client's app.config then it can read it.

I have two questions:
1. Why does it work that way? Why a file the resides inside the DAL project can only read the client's project app.config file and not it's own?
2. It seems rather silly to add app.config to each client project that connects to the
 same DAL project, hence to the same DB. How can I have one app.config file  mutual to all 
of my projects? Or how can I make sure that the DAL project's .cs file will read it's 
own app.config file?

Thanks ahead

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3255958/724944

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1009227/380099